# spring mvc controller test org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc

```
Can someone help on this?

 I am getting the below exception(org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException) when I run this test.
```

In the response I get this Headers.

Headers = {Accept=[application/octet-stream, text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1, application/xml, text/xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/*+xml, multipart/form-data, application/json;charset=UTF-8, application/*+json;charset=UTF-8, */*]}

The add method in the controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addTrain", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void addTrain(@RequestBody Train train) {
        trainService.addTrain(train);
    }


I am doing JUnit test for a method. Below is my Test class and MockHttpServletRequest and MockHttpSErvletResponse.

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/config/webapp-config.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TrainControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @InjectMocks
    TrainController trainController;

    @Mock
    private TrainService trainService;

    private final List<Train> trainList = new ArrayList<Train>(); 

    private Train train;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Process mock annotations
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();


        train = new Train();
        train.setId(12L);
        train.setName("chennai");
        train.setSpeed(100);
        train.setDiesel(true);

        Train train1 = new Train();

        train1.setId(15L);
        train1.setName("kovai");
        train1.setSpeed(150);
        train1.setDiesel(false);

        trainList.add(train);
        trainList.add(train1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddTrainList() throws Exception {
        Mockito.doNothing().when(trainService).addTrain(train);
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/trains/addTrain")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
}
```

### The request and reponse are below:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = POST
         Request URI = /trains/addTrain
          Parameters = {}
             Headers = {}

             Handler:
                Type = com.xvitcoder.angualrspringapp.controller.TrainController
              Method = public void com.xvitcoder.angualrspringapp.controller.TrainController.addTrain(com.xvitcoder.angualrspringapp.beans.Train)

               Async:
   Was async started = false
        Async result = null

  **Resolved Exception:
                Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException**

        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:

**MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 415
       Error message = null**


        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

Answer (score 4):

Your request has to specify the Content-type header from one of the acceptable ones.

Try changing your mock request as below:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(post("/trains/addTrain").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Resolved Exception:
                Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

Comment: Resolved Exception:
                Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException